# If $f$ is irreducible over $\mathcal{O}_K$, is $f$ irreducible over $K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ be an algebraic number and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be a number field. I want to show that if $f\in\mathcal{O}_K[x]$ is irreducible over $\mathcal{O}_K$, then $f$ is irreducible over $K$.

Suppose $f=gh$ for some $g,h\in K$. My idea is to multiply $g$ and $h$ to some $a,b\in\mathcal{O}_K$ such that $G=ag,H=bh\in\mathcal{O}_K[x]$. Then $(ab)f = GH$ and show that $G$ or $H$ is a constant but I don't know how to proceed. This is like Gauss's Lemma but Gauss's Lemma requires $\mathcal{O}_K$ to be a UFD which might not be true.

I also think that this is false. However, I can't produce a counterexample. Any suggestion is well-appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There's an analogue of Gauss's lemma for Dedekind domains such as $\mathcal{O}_K$.
It is $c(fg)=c(f)c(g)$ where $c(f)$ is the content of  $f$, that is the **ideal** generated
by its coefficients. So all works well if  $\mathcal{O}_K$ has class number one, but
odd things can happen otherwise.

Let $I$ and $J$ be non-principal ideals with $IJ=(a)$ principal. If $f$ and $g$
have contents $I$ and $J$ respectively, then $fg$ has content $a$, so $fg/a
\in\mathcal{O}_K[x]$ has content $1$, and is irreducible over $\mathcal{O}_K$
but not over $K$.

As an example, let $I=J=(2,\sqrt{-6})$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$
and $f=g=2X+\sqrt{-6}$. Then $f^2/2=2X^2+2\sqrt{-6}X-3$ is irreducible over
$\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ but not over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-6})$.